# Do I need to keep the ngx_pagespeed source code after compiling it into nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have built `nginx` with the `ngx_pagespeed` module with the following configure flag: `--add-module=ngx_pagespeed`

Do I still need to keep the original ngx_pagespeed directory after it finishes compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you compiled and then installed nginx (`make install`) you shouldn't need the extra directory for the module anymore (assuming this folder you speak of is the source code for the module, and not a folder created by the module when nginx is run).

However, you will likely want to keep the directory around for when you update nginx and recompile in the future (or you can just redone load the page speed module again).

Comment: When I run nginx with modpagespeed on; I get blank responses.

Comment: @Aman That's not the focus of your question - for support with the page speed module you should be reaching out to their support if it is not returning everything.  Check your error.log file to see if there's any kind of error which would trigger blank pages; my guess is there is.  Open a new question for any different issues, as well - one question per issue is how this site works, generally.